# Redefine print to open, write in a log file, close

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, nohup

**Background:** I've noticed that the trick `nohup python test.py &` usually doesn't work because the output is not saved correctly in real-time in `nohup.out`. The solutions given [in this famous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919980/nohup-is-not-writing-log-to-output-file) (such as `nohup python -u`) don't always work, as shown [in my other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753765/nohup-and-python-u-it-still-doesnt-log-data-in-realtime).

**Question**: I have used `print(...)` everywhere in my code, so I don't want to change this and replace it by another logging function. Is it possible to redefine `print` to do this instead:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def print(s):
    with open('out.txt', 'a+') as f:
        f.write(str(s) + '\n')
    old_print(s)     # how to print it with the standard print too?
```

Comment: What's wrong with the first answer to your earlier question?

Comment: @user2357112 if I remember well, solutions with `flush` didn't work in 100% of the cases for me.

Comment: If `flush` didn't work for you, there's no reason to expect `close` to work any better. You should probably look into the root cause of your nohup problems; what you're doing now is basically shotgun debugging.

Comment: Open, write, close would be fine for me (already tested), and then I would be 100% sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can override the builtin function.

Consider this test.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def new_print(*args, **kwargs):
    old_print('HELLO!')

import __builtin__
old_print = __builtin__.print
__builtin__.print = new_print

print(100)  # -> HELLO!
old_print(200)  # -> 200
```

This also works if you redefine the builtin function only once in a sigle module, and then just import it -- it will affect the whole app.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import test

print(300)  # HELLO!
```

But you still have to import from future in py2, always. Otherwise, print will not be a builtin function, but an operator, and thus never overridden.

This trick will also work in py3, with the exception that the module name is `builtins`. So the code could be like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def new_print(*args, **kwargs):
    old_print('HELLO!')

try:
    import __builtin__ as bi  # py2
except ImportError:
    import builtins as bi # py3

old_print = bi.print
bi.print = new_print

print(100)
old_print(200)
```